# GuzzleHttp\Client returning 404

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, guzzle

I have started to use GuzzleHttp\Client and I have problem to get response from REST API, because I am getting error 404 code. I don't understand it because when I copied url from my code and paste into browser I will see json response. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://login:password@url_to_api/get/some_products');
$json = $response->json();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, that you can add your login credentials like that. 
Here is the right way: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#auth